# Carousel text changes relevant to image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image slider set up, I want to be able to display text underneath the slider and when the users clicks "next" the text beneath changes so that it's relevant to the image above, when the user clicks "previous" the text slides back so that it's relevant to the above image.

```js
  var text = ['1', '2', '3', '4',]

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slick-next").click(function () {
      $(".page-number p").append(text)
    } )
 
  } );
```

```css
.page-number p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18%;
  bottom: 0%;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
 <div class="overlay-content_2">
        <div class="slick-content">
             <img src="inside.jpg">
          <img src="single.jpg">
          <img src="inside.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-number"><p>Structural Collapse</p></div>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: maybe this pen will help you: https://codepen.io/KenanYusuf/pen/dMWyoK